# A multithreaded algorithm for multiplying an nxn matrix with $\Theta(n^2/lgn)$ parallelism

Tags: multithreading, algorithm

I want to find a multithreaded algorithm to multiply an $n x n$ matrix by an n-vector that achieves $\Theta(n^2/lgn)$ parallelism while maintaining $\Theta(n^2)$ work.

I know an illegal solution but any tips on how to make the span go down to $\Theta(lgn)$?

Comment: What do you mean by "illegal"? Are there some constraints it violates? (I doubt you mean it steals processor time or takes hostages...)

Comment: Illegal since i have twofold parallel for loops and the equation $y_i=y_i+a_ij x_j$ then due to races I might get wrong results.

Comment: Can you get the span down to Theta(log n) with infinitely many processors?

Comment: Well that is indeed my question. I mean one could do those multiplication with infinitely many processors in Theta(lgn) since they are independent, but adding them up is less trivial, then I encounter the problem of racing, which is considered illegal.

Comment: Ok I guess summing those elements is not that hard.

Answer (score 2):

There is an implementation of this problem with procedure named **MAT-VEC** in **CLRS** textbook. But its span is **Theta of N**. To pull it down to **logarithmic span**, you can replace serial summation in inner for loop by using multithreaded divide & conquer strategy. To do that recursively divide the range and spawn one side with parallel to other then synchronize and return the summed value left+right.